# Service onStartCommand and onCreate executed from the same Thread as Activity's onCreate

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Android OS never stops surprising me. I wish i'd know whats the rule opon which they decide weither to kill your Thread or not while your app is on background. This is very confusing, at first i was sure that they run Services code on special service threads, and any thread created from the Service Thread is not eliminated when app goes to the background, but then when i Log Thread.currentThread() i see that both Activity's code and Service's code runs on the same main Thread, while as documented, services can run on background while activities cant.

How is this whole thing work? how do they decide which Thread to kill and which not? how do they decide weither an Object is in use or that its memory can be freed? at first i expected it to work like in standart Java enviroment but they got everything changed in an unclear and not very documented way...

anyone here can give me a reference to a good article about this issue or even better can explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, when dealing with Services you should probably read the [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) doc. A relevant line from there is:

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process.

All of this is quite well documented actually. The Android OS does not kill specific threads, only entire processes. You can read more of this in the [Process Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle) section of the same document.